# Navigating to a view (push) from a search results table (UISearchController) and keeping the search results in place

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uisearchcontroller

I have a search results table (`UISearchController`) that is presented on a view that exists on a navigation stack. I present the search controller and table on my view like this:

```
    _searchResultsTableViewController = [[CalendarSearchResultsTableViewController alloc] init];
_searchResultsTableViewController.delegate = self;

_searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:_searchResultsTableViewController];
_searchController.delegate = self;
_searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = NO;
_searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = YES;
_searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = YES;
_searchController.active = YES;

_searchController.searchBar.delegate = self;

UIEdgeInsets adjustForTabbarInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, CGRectGetHeight(self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame), 0);
_searchResultsTableViewController.tableView.contentInset = adjustForTabbarInsets;
_searchResultsTableViewController.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = adjustForTabbarInsets;

[self.navigationController presentViewController:_searchController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

This presents a `UISearchBar` over the `UINavigationBar` and the search table appears as expected. When the user selects a search result from the table, I want to present a view for the selection by pushing it onto the navigation stack while the search results remain in place. The way I have it working now is that the view that presented the search controller opens the view, but this requires the search controller to be dismissed because the `search result view` is presented behind the search results table.

**How can I make it so that the search controller pushes the `search result view` onto the navigation stack, allowing the user to navigate back to the search results?**

An example of how I expect this to work can be found in the iOS Mail of Calendar app (when you search).

My `navigationController` property in the search results controller is nil, so I cannot currently present the `search result view` from there.

The project is in both Objective-C and Swift, so answers in either is fine. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried to keep your search results in the initial table view controller as well as search term - so in viewWillAppear you can set that search term and use serach results as a data source?

Comment: I'm working with a legacy table view unfortunately, so I'm trying to build this search table on top of the one that's currently there. The search results come from a web call, so they have separate data sources.

Comment: Yeah sure, but that doesn't stop you from saving these results. For instance, at the start you have empty array(most likely nil) of results and array of options. After the search that array should contain some of the data. So far so good. If you come back to the screen you can check that array(and search term) and if there is some then present search bar again.

Comment: Another option worth mentioning is actually creating navigation controller and presenting him with root seach bar from tableView - have you tried that ?

Comment: I have tried presenting the search bar in a navigation controller, that's part of the issues I was running into because I couldn't get it to appear like it should (search bar slides down from top of view over the existing nav bar).

Comment: I've tried a similar approach to your suggestion about retaining search results, but I just hid the search results table and search bar. That solution works, but it doesn't have the same navigation animation of the search result view sliding onto the navigation stack (because it happens below the search table).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133835/discussion-between-miknash-and-timgcarlson).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think there are 3 small changes you need to make.

1. `_searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = YES;`
2. `[self presentViewController:_searchController animated:YES completion:nil];`
3. `self.definesPresentationContext = YES;`  // in `viewDidLoad` of the viewController that presented the searchController

Comment: This is exactly what I was missing, thank you! I figured it was something simple I was missing, and turns out it was a combination of simple things. Enjoy your bounty!

Comment: Sorry!, I had problem same as @timgcarlson, but I try this solution not work. maybe I miss something more. thank you

Comment: @LeangSocheat found any solution? This solution is not working for me